# ORA-01722: invalid number, but removing DECODE statement returns results

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have a SQL query (below) where I'm getting an ORA-01722: invalid number error. Pretty common.

```
SELECT pt.DISPLAYNAME PARAM_NAME,
  DECODE(rp.PARAMTYPE, 'POVLOC', l.PARTNAME, p.PARAM_VALUE) PARAM_VALUE
FROM schema2.OTHER_PARAMS p
JOIN schema2.TPARAMETER rp
  ON rp.R_ID = 10230
 AND p.PARAM_NAME = rp.PARAMNAME
JOIN schema2.TPARAMETER_TL pt
  ON rp.PARAMID = pt.PARAMID
 AND pt.LANGUAGE = 'en'
LEFT JOIN schema2.TPARTITION l
  ON l.PARTITION = p.PARAM_VALUE
WHERE p.F_ID = 3669
ORDER BY rp.SEQ
```

Once I remove the DECODE statement and just have the PARAMTYPE column I get results. 1 column with PARAM_NAME (DISPLAYNAME column), the other with PARAM_VAL (PARAMTYPE column). All the datatypes in the DECODE are Varchar, so there are no conversions from number to char or vice versa. That's usually the most common reason this invalid number error occurs.

If it's not clear from above, what I want to do is insert some if/then logic on the PARAMTYPE column to update it. I was thinking about using a CASE statement for the PARAMTYPE variable, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is.

Comment: Can you write it as SELECT pt.DISPLAYNAME PARAM_NAME,
  rp.PARAMTYPE, l.PARTNAME, p.PARAM_VALUE 
FROM ... and tell the result, specially the values of rp.PARAMTYPE, l.PARTNAME, p.PARAM_VALUE (if it is few)

Comment: ```CAST``` paramtype as a string (to_char or otherwise).  Its a type conversion problem.

Comment: Do I wrap CAST around the DECODE? Not sure of the syntax

Comment: Use TO_CHAR function - `DECODE( TO_CHAR(rp.PARAMTYPE, 'POVLOC'), l.PARTNAME, p.PARAM_VALUE) PARAM_VALUE`

Comment: Are F_ID and R_ID numeric?  A common cause is STRING_COL = number, which Oracle will convert into TO_NUMBER(STRING_COL) = number, and hence runs the risk of that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DECODE result values have both number and varchar, then you should force the first one to be a varchar to avoid convertion errors. In your case, just replace l.PARTNAME by TO_CHAR(l.PARTNAME).